# Cannot convert value of type and my problem

Tags: ios, swift

I have code:

```
typealias animationBlock = () -> Void

func fade(withAnimation animations: animationBlock ) {
    UIView.transition(with: blankView!, duration: TimeInterval(kAnimationDuration), options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: animations)
  }
```

[image]

I tried a lot and can not what is wrong

Comment: What's `animationBlock`?

Comment: It is a datatype issue,  UIView.transition accept other datatype and you have give animationBlock type. That means your animationBlock and accept types seems difference

Comment: @DávidPásztor sry, i am update information

Comment: @IMHiteshSurani I understand, but I don’t understand how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a closure parameter is optional, it becomes `@escaping`, so mark your `animations` parameter with `@escaping`:

```
typealias animationBlock = () -> Void

func fade(withAnimation animations: @escaping animationBlock) {
    UIView.transition(with: blankView!,
                      duration: TimeInterval(kAnimationDuration),
                      options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                      animations: animations)
}
```